# Java constants for Postgresql's days-of-week

Tags: java, postgresql, dayofweek

Postgresql returns day-of-week using `EXTRACT` with `dow` in the following fashion: 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, all the way to 6 which is Saturday, [see official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

I am looking for some official constants either in Java proper or in JDBC or perhaps some standard library (Apache Commons?) that match this numbering.

Comment: Can you show us some SQL/Java code where this actually matters?  It almost sounds breaking the abstraction of JDBC.

Comment: why don't you use isodow instead dow?

Comment: @Rcordoval that is the correct solution, please write it up as an answer and I will accept it. I did not realize `isodow` exists.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am currently writing a query that is finding customers that currently have a Friday 10:00 AM in their respective time zone, so I need to pass in the concept of "Friday" into the query and of course I don't want to hard-code it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the same [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) you should use `isodow`:

The day of the week as Monday (1) to Sunday (7)

Comment: ...which I can match to the official `DayOfWeek` class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> I am looking for some official constants either in Java proper

Yes, Java defines the seven day-of-week values in the  [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum using the same standard ISO 8601 definition as the `isodow` function in Postgres where a week runs from Monday-Sunday with days numbered 1-7.

```
DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.getValue()  // Returns an `int` 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.
```

> 3

## `java.time.DayOfWeek` enum

As the [Answer by Rcordoval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50405039/642706) suggests, use the [Postgres function `isodow`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

The “iso” in `isodow` refers to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard and [its definition of week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) where days are numbered 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

Java supports that same definition of week in its [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum. That class defines seven objects for you, one for each day of the week such as [`DayOfWeek.MONDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#MONDAY). To get each object’s day-of-week number, 1-7 for Monday-Sunday, call `DayOfWeek::getValue`. But in your Java coding, focus on using and passing around the `DayOfWeek` objects themselves rather than mere integer numbers.

```
int dowNumber = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.getValue() ;
```

> 3

Going from the integer number to a `DayOfWeek` object is bit trickier, as we need to access a Java array using an index. The index means zero-based counting, so subtract one from your day-of-week number. Wednesday is day # 3, so subtract 1 for a result of 2 to access `DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY`.

```
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.values()[ 3-1 ] ;  // Get object named `WEDNESDAY` using zero-based index counting, so 3 - 1 = 2.
```

> dow.toString(): WEDNESDAY

By the way, to automatically localize the name of the day-of-week, call [`DayOfWeek::getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-).

## Java rather than SQL

> I am currently writing a query that is finding customers that currently have a Friday 10:00 AM in their respective time zone, so I need to pass in the concept of "Friday" into the query and of course I don't want to hard-code it.

May be better to do this work in Java using the industry-leading *java.time* classes rather than in SQL.

You must be very careful about time zones. Be explicit with time zones rather than relying on implicit default zones.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Next, get the following Friday, or stick with today if it is already a Friday. Use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) to adjust between dates, specifically the one found in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html).

```
LocalDate nextOrSameFriday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) ) ;
```

You said you were aiming at 10 AM.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 ) ;  // 10 AM.
```

Combine with date and zone to get a specific moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Adjust into UTC by extracting a `Instant` object. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Formulate your SQL to query your database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
String sql = "SELECT * from tbl WHERE when_col = ? ; " ;
…
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

And retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

In this approach you have need for the `dow` or `isodow` functions in Postgres.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Calendar` constants minus 1 so you can match the PostgreSQL values ie: `Calendar.SUNDAY = 1`

Comment: I am looking for official constants, if I start subtracting 1 I might as well write my own enum.

Comment: And I would absolutely use them any time I could but here unfortunately Postgres does not go by the ISO standard...

Comment: @DamCx You are slightly missing the point (but +1 to you).  The OP wants to use a Postgres Java class which is in tune with the actual driver.  `java.util.Calendar` knows nothing of Postgres.

Comment: I would avoid the `Calendar` class if I can, it’s long outdated and poorly designed. And, @DamCx, there’s nothing official about its constants other than they are declared constants in this outdated class. Yes, that makes them official, perhaps, but it certainly doesn’t make them the only official ones.